# How to define unknown prop warnings for a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Is it good practice / possible to generate unknown prop warnings for a component? I think it would help to recognize quickly errors in the code. As far as I know props not defined in propTypes will just be ignored.

For example if I have a `Box` component that accepts a `color` prop, the following prop would not generate a warning/error:

```
<Box colour="red">1</Box>
```

This is just a simple example, but sometimes there are multiple props and such naming that mistakes can happen.

Comment: If you have an option to move to TypeScript it might be a good option to consider.

Comment: Yes props not declared or used in the component will be ignored. You can use Typescript  by the way for this